# Is there a way to refer to function arguments in typescript definitions?

Tags: typescript, types

I have a `{string: Function}` map `a`:

```
const a: A = {
    foo: (x: string) => 8,
    bar: (y: number, z: boolean) => 6,
}
```

I then transform it such that every mapped function has a different type of return value:

```
const b: B = {
    foo: (x: string) => (8).toString(),
    bar: (y: number, z: boolean) => (6).toString(),
}
```

In TypeScript, is there any way to describe type `B` as derived from `A`, in my dream world, I'd like to be able to do:

```
type A = {
    foo: (string) => number
    bar: (number, boolean) => number
}
type B = {
    [K in keyof A]: (E in argsof A[K]) => string
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dreams come true in Typescript :)

You can achieve this in Typescript 3.0 using [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) and [Tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897):

```
type A = {
    foo: (s: string) => number
    bar: (n: number, b: boolean) => number
}


type ArgumentTypes<T extends (...a: any[]) => any> = T extends (...a: infer A) => any ? A : []; 
type B = {
    [K in keyof A]:  (...a:ArgumentTypes<A[K]>) => string 
}

let b: B;
b.foo("") // works
b.foo(1) // error
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using the built in `Parameters<T>` type as of Typescript 3.1:

```
type B = {
  [K in keyof A]:  (...a: Parameters<A[K]>) => string
}
```

This isn't explicitly documented in the Typescript [docs on conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) but similar conditional types are, like `ReturnType<T>`, you can see them all in the [source](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es5.d.ts).

With this in mind we could go a step further and relate B to the return type of our transforming function using `ReturnType<T>`:

```
const transformingFunction: (n: number) => string = (n: number) => n.toString();

type B = {
  [K in keyof A]:  (...a: Parameters<A[K]>) => ReturnType<typeof transformingFunction>
}
```

So now, if we want to change the return type of our transforming function, it can be done in one place, i.e. on the function itself without breaking the signature of B.